# What type of connector use smart phones adapter?

Tags: connector

What is this type of connectors?

http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Universal-Qi-Wireless-Charger-Receiver-Charging-Adapter-Receptor-Receiver-Pad-Coil-For-Xiaomi-THL-OnePlus-Honor/32334054624.html?spm=2114.01010208.0.472.8hRw0V

Comment: Is this a joke ?

Comment: uhhh, micro usb?

Comment: Ask the supplier.  We are not his volunteer technical support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connector at the top of the main pic. is micro USB. If you mean how does the charger work, it's a "wireless charging" inductor that couples with a "base" inductor to create a transformer to convert ac mains voltage down to 5V for usb charging.